# Catch NFC NDEF-Text-tags system-wide?

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc, ndef

My Windows Phone 8 app should react to `NDEF-Text`-encoded NFC tags, no matter if the user is currently in another app or on the homescreen. On Android, this works by having the app "subscribe" to certain tags (e.g., NDEF-Text, in my case), and the operating system will allow the user to choose from a list of apps if more than one app can process the scanned tag. Is there anything comparable for WP8? At the moment, I am using

```
 ProximityDevice _device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
 long _subscriptionIdNdef = _device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", MessageReceivedHandler);
```

in my MainPage-class, which works fine, but obviously only if the user has launched my app prior to scanning a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, for the moment NDEF-Text tags can't be handled by third party apps on Windows Phone 8.

If you want the OS to launch your app, you will have to either use the NDEF-LaunchApp record type or register a custom URI scheme.

Comment: Thanks, Olivier! So I could encode a tag with both a LaunchApp-record and my Text-Record, and read the Text-Record immediately after the app was launched (by the LaunchRecord), without the user having to scan the tag again?